# Kubernetes internal nginx ingress controller with SSL termination & ssl-passthrough

Tags: ssl, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress

I am very new to using helm charts for deploying containers, and I have also never worked with nginx controllers or ingress controllers.
However, I am being asked to look into improving our internal nginx ingress controllers to allow for SSL-passthrough.

Right now we have external (public facing) and internal controllers. Where the public ones allow SSL-passthrough, and the internal ones have SSL-termination.
I have also been told that nginx is a reverse proxy, and that it works based on headers in the URL.

I am hoping someone can help me out on this helm chart that I have for the internal ingress controllers.
Currently I am under the impression that having SSL termination as well as SSL-passthrough on the same ingress controllers would not be possible.
Answered this one myself: https://serversforhackers.com/c/tcp-load-balancing-with-nginx-ssl-pass-thru

Our current (internal) ingress code:

```
---

rbac:
  create: true

controller:
  ingressClass: nginx-internal
  service:
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: 0.0.0.0/0
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:eu:110:certificate/62-b3
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: !!str 443
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: !!str 3600

    targetPorts:
      https: 80

  replicaCount: 3

defaultBackend:
  replicaCount: 3
```

Can I simply add the following? :

```
controller:
    extraArgs:
        enable-ssl-passthrough: ""
```

Note: The above piece of code is what we use on our external ingress controller.

additionally, I found this:
[Ingress and SSL Passthrough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48025879/ingress-and-ssl-passthrough)

Can I just go and mix the annotations? Or do annotations only care about the 'top domain level' where the annotation comes from?
eg:

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io
```

Both come from the domain kubernetes.io, or does the sub-domain make a difference?
I mean: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md
That page doesn't show any of the service.beta annotations on it ..

What's the difference between the extraArg ssl-passthrough configuration and the ssl-passthrough configuration in the annotations?

I'm looking mostly for an answer on how to get the SSL-passthrough working without breaking the SSL-termination on the internal ingress controllers.
However, any extra information to gain more insight and knowledge as far as my other questions go would also be very appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found the answer to my own question(s):
The annotations appear to be 'configuration items'. I'm using quotes because i can't find a better term.
The extraArgs parameter is where you can pass any parameter to the controller as if it were a commandline parameter.
And I think it is also safe to say that the annotations can be either any of the same top-level domain. I have not found any that weren't from another domain then kubernetes.io

To get my ingress controller to work side-by-side with the SSL-termination controller the helm chart looks as following:

```
---
rbac:
  create: true

controller:
  ingressClass: nginx-internal-ssl-passthrough
  service:
    annotations:
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: "true"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-additional-resource-tags: "tag3=value3, tag3=value3, tag3=value3, tag3=value3"
    targetPorts:
      https: 443
  replicaCount: 2
  extraArgs:
    enable-ssl-passthrough: ""

defaultBackend:
  replicaCount: 2
```

Toke me about 2 days of researching/searching the web & 6 deployments to get the whole setup working with AWS nlb, ssl-passthrough enabled, cross-zone loadbalancing, etc. But after having found the following pages it went pretty fast:
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

This last page helped me a lot. If someone else gets to deploy SSL-termination and SSL-passthrough for either public or private connections, I hope this helps too.

Comment: Full code can be found also here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62030504/8490256

Answer (score 0):

From here you can find out how to redirect the HTTPS traffic to the pod without SSL-termination
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66767691/1938507