# Unauthorized 401 when trying to access Kubernetes API through curl

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver

I am running a local Kubernetes cluster (v1.28) and running into an issue when trying to access the API with curl.

`curl https://192.168.1.100:6443 --cert /path/to/cert --key /path/to/key --cacert /path/to/ca`

I receive the following error:

`{   "kind": "Status",   "apiVersion": "v1",   "metadata": {},   "status": "Failure",   "message": "Unauthorized",   "reason": "Unauthorized",   "code": 401 }`

Is there a configuration step I'm missing to allow access?

I'm able to interact with `kubectl` and run commands.  I was expecting to see something like this:

`{   "paths": [     "/api",     "/api/v1",     ....`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a working kubectl you can use proxy command, proxy command works as a reverse proxy and forwards the requests to the API server.

```
kubectl proxy --port=8099
```

then you can browse the API with curl

```
curl localhost:8099
```

Comment: Using the kubectl proxy command allows me to curl locally on the kubernetes cluster.  The problem is that I need to allow an external application to access the Kubernetes API.  As a test, I created another cluster using minikube and was able to use the same curl command in my original post.  Not sure what I need to configure to allow that curl command to work.

Answer (score 0):

2 things has to be done:

- enable TLS passthrough in the ingress, to allow the client certificate to reach the API and avoid the 401 unauthorized (see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48025879/ingress-and-ssl-passthrough#54670939))
- add the IP/DNS additional entry in the SANs of the API server (see [this](https://gist.github.com/abdennour/450163a67ed7b4e3fd5813276ffca462) for kubeadm based kubernetes cluster).